# Searching for all events in a geographic area using bandsintown API

Tags: javascript, json, rest, api, parsing

So, I'm trying to pull all events for a particular area, using bandsintown API.  For example, I'm interested in pulling all upcoming concerts for San Francisco, CA. The key here is that I want all events, rather than a particular artist.

Using some code I've found on stackoverflow, I've tweaked it a little to pull data from only CA.  Here's the code:

```
// HTTP GET call to BandsInTown API
function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback) { //theURL or a path to file
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
        if (callback) {
            callback(data);
        }                   
    }
    else {
        //alert("error loading JSON doc");
    }
};

httpRequest.open('GET', theUrl, true); 
httpRequest.send(null);
}

//extracts data from api for each artist
function parseEvent(artist) {
var url = "https://rest.bandsintown.com/artists/" + artist + "/events?app_id=9c42d4dc9c1397201a4e3dc4d0bb840c&venue.region=" + region;

httpGetAsync(url, function(data) {
    var numEvents = Object.keys(data).length;
    console.log(numEvents)
    //var events = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < numEvents; j++) {
      if (data[j].venue.region == 'CA'){
        document.write(data[j].venue.name + "-> ");
        document.write("LAT:" + data[j].venue.latitude + " " + "LNG:" + data[j].venue.longitude);
        document.write("ARTIST: " + data[j].artists[3].name);
        document.write("DATE: " + data[j].datetime);
        document.write("Region:" + data[j].venue.region);
        document.write(" " + j + " "); 
        }
    }
}); 
}

var artists = ["Twenty One Pilots", "Atmosphere", "Vince Staples", "STRFKR", "Rainbow Kitten Surprise", "Mac Demarco", "Hippo Campus", "Drake", "John Legend", "Rihanna", "Flying Lotus", "MGMT", "Jason Derulo", "M83", "Bon Iver", "Childish Gambino","The Del McCoury Band","Dawes"];
var region = "CA";

for (var i = 0; i < artists.length; i++) {
parseEvent(artists[i]);
document.write(" ---NEXT ARTIST--- ");
}
```

So, I put in the 'artists' array just to get this working and see if I could connect to the API successfully - but ultimately, I'd like to tweak this to pull all events, not just a particular artists.  I've yet to find any examples of this, and bandsintown documentation is sparse.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible; their API simply doesn't support it. If you look at their official [documentation](https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/Bandsintown/PublicAPI/3.0.0), you'll notice there are only two possible endpoints: you can get artist info, and you can get events for a particular artist. Both involve specifying an artist.

Comment: oh noo.  That's unfortunate.  The only workaround I can think of is just pulling a massive list of artists.. but this seems silly.  Can you think of any sort of creative workaround?  Thanks brother.

Comment: You can actually get events by location from their [own website](https://www.bandsintown.com/c/san-francisco-ca?came_from=253&sort_by_filter=Number+of+RSVPs), it's just their API that doesn't support it. So if you really wanted to, you could build a scraper that loads their website and extracts the info. As far as I can tell it's right there in JSON format so it shouldn't be _too_ difficult.

Comment: Thanks.  I built a webscraper modeled after this tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QICvAVZJKO4.  It works, but unfortunately, the bandsintown website only displays 18 events in the page source.  You can click 'show all' events, but it's not reflected in the html, which makes it impossible to scrape more than 18 events.  For example, viewing events in San Francisco at the url: "https://www.bandsintown.com/?came_from=257&sort_by_filter=Number+of+RSVPs" , you can 'show all' events but the page source only shows the initial banner 18 events.  Is this just the reality of the page structure?